# Wiring a 3-way dimmer/fan control switch with two 14-3 cables in the switch box

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I have a 3 way dimmer/fan control switch that I need to install in a box with two existing 14-3 wires. I want the other 3 way switch to control the light only.

In the box, I have a 14-3 (on the left side) that comes from the existing 3 way switch. The red and black are live when the breaker is on. The other 14-3 (on the right), goes to the fan/light.

Could I please get some details explaining which wires from the box connect to which wires on the switch?

[image: switch wires]

[image: switch box image]

Comment: How are you testing the wires for live-ness?  Also, what make and model is the fan control in question?

Comment: I tested the 14-3 wires coming from the 3 way switch (left side wires in my pic), by turning the breaker on and using a non-contact voltage tester. 

Make and model of the dimmer/fan control is: Legrand preset dimmer and fan control LSCLDC163PWCCV4

Comment: Is any of a) replacing the cable between the two switch boxes, b) adding another part at this switch box (that'd have to go inside the wall unless you wished to use a bigger box), or c) having the fan and light both be 3-way switched acceptable to you?

Comment: I guess out of those 3 choices you gave, (c) having both the fan and light be 3 way switched is my preference. 

Just to be clear, you’re saying that having ONLY the light be 3 way switched is not possible with this switch and my wiring?

Comment: Examining the left cable: if you throw the other 3-way switch, does it change which wires are hot?   Examining the right cable: Are *any* of those wires hot?  What other wires and cables are involved, can we get a pic looking into the back of the box with that other switch pulled out of the way (but not disconnected)?  Also, same deal other 3-way?

Comment: Also, we see a red black white group on the left of your photo.  *Are all those in the same cable?*  Same question, right red black white group.  https://www.legrand.us/-/media/brands/passandseymour/resources/installation-instructions/other/ps-dual-slide-de-hummer-fan-control-and-dimmer-install-sheet.ashx

Comment: Harper- throwing the other 3 way switch does not change which wires are hot; it’s still the black and red that are hot whether the switch is thrown or not. That other switch you see in the pic is on a different circuit and has a 14-2 & 14-3 connected to it. It’s a 3 way dimmer switch controlling a light in another room. The left side red, black, and white wires are all in the same cable. That cable goes to the 3 way switch box. The right hand side are also part of the same cable. That’s a new 14-3 I pulled to the ceiling for separate control of the fan and light.

Comment: @DMG -- it's possible to get what you want, but you need an extra part called a *relay* (effectively, a remote-controlled switch) to do it, and installing that relay isn't quite as straightforward as installing a dimmer.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Thank you for the relay information. Could you please explain how to wire your option (c) suggestion? Can I have the dimmer and fan be independently controlled and the 3 way toggle control both the fan and light? I did confirm that the hot wire from the breaker comes into the existing 3 way switch box. It’s connected to the other black wires and pigtailed to the black common screw on the 3 way. The other brass screws have the black and red from the 14-3 as travelers going to the dimmer/fan box.

Comment: @DMG -- come to think of it, is returning this fan control and getting a different one instead an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Is this possible and to code?: Eliminate the 3 way toggle switch. Use the 14-3 black wire only and carry the hot wire from the breaker to the dimmer/fan box. Then, use a single pole dimmer/fan switch.

Comment: @DMG it depends on if Code requires the light in question to be controllable from the other location.  The issue with your current fan control, though, is that it can't be put on the LOAD side of a pair of 3-ways, only the LINE side. Oops!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Can you please expand on the Load side, Line side comment?

Comment: @DMG -- the control you have has one power wire coming in for both the Fan and the Light sides, which means it needs to be fed with always-hot

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: ok, so would the black or red travelers from the 3 way be an “always hot”? Can you explain which wires to connect for your option (c)?

Comment: @DMG -- neither of them are "always hot", they're both travelers unfortunately

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: thank you, it is clear to me know. Would you be able to explain how to wire your option (c) suggestion?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I just eliminated the 3 way switch and connected the 14-3 black wire to the hot from the breaker. I installed a single pole dimmer/fan switch instead of that 3 way dimmer/fan switch. I will check the MA code for this maneuver, but this actually works well since the now eliminated 3 way toggle switch seemed unnecessary and we hardly used it. Thank you for all your help!